# Binding issues with for attribute in label tag in IE7

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, internet-explorer-7

Hi I'm not able to put bindings in `ids` and `fors` attributes in IE7. This example works fine in Chrome, IE8, ..., but doesn't work on IE7 or less

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app id="ng-app" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>fjseif</title>
</head>
<body>

 <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <script src="json2.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<input type="radio" id="in{{1+1}}" name="lala">
<label for="in{{2}}">Hello1</label>

<input type="radio" id="in{{1+2}}" name="lala">
<label for="in{{3}}">Hello1</label>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The label with tag for "in{{3}}" does'nt bind to the input of id "in{{1+2}}"

I believe this happens because the `for to id` linking happens at the DOM Load on IE7, and doesn't happen again after the compiling.

Is this the real reason why it doesn't work, and if yes, how can I solve it ?

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wttYe/ (JSFiddle doesn't work on IE7, but you get the idea)

Comment: Ever figure this issue out? Running into the same problem with checkboxes. Clicking the box itself works fine but clicking any of the checkbox labels only checks the last checkbox.

Comment: Hi, i can remember this problem but I didn't find any solution. You can maybe attach an event handler yourself and not use the fortag at all when the browser is lte ie7

Comment: That is a good idea for a work around - was not too worried about IE7 but was annoyed when this particular thing did not just work. Thanks!